# error 6003: The value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I did the reverse engineering and I can not load my entities from my SQL Server database:

> One or more errors occurred while loading schema information.
>   Error 6003: The value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull. Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Share some relevant code. It is hard to understand what the issue is

Comment: @Shyju there's no code iam just trying to import sql database